# Passing auth param in python code

Tags: python, magento

I am hitting a Magento url by advance rest client, and passing some of the auth params like: consumer_key, consumer_secret , access token and access secret token. Signature method and nonce is there automatically. I want to hit the same by python to get the response. Request type is GET. How to pass these params with the python code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hitting the Magento REST API from python using the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [requests_oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib).

Something roughly along these lines:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


def make_get_request(path, params):
    """Make a GET request to the Magento API."""

    client_key = 'Your Client Key'
    client_secret = 'Your Client Secret'
    resource_owner_key = 'Your Resource Owner Key'
    resource_owner_secret = 'Your Resource Owner Secret'

    auth = OAuth1(client_key,
                  client_secret,
                  resource_owner_key,
                  resource_owner_secret)

    res = requests.get(url=path, params=params, auth=auth)

    return res.json()
```